# Specified Column Width, Centered Positioned Colum with Doouble Line (with bold line) in first row

Tags: tables, two-column

How to create similar to this table in LaTeX for IEEE Transaction 
I am trying to make using similar to this one but cant make similar to the attached [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b1rc83ljjlh1ig5/Screenshot%202014-03-08%2020.37.06.png). [image]

```
\usepackage{array}



\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{jkhafj ahjfha hfjah fjahf jhasjf ha}\\
\label{Table1}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{jkahfjadhfjhajfhahfa}\\
\hline  fhjahfa, `$r$' (nm) & ajlhfjkahfha & ajhgjadhjgha &     .ngjadhfjkdahfg(\%) \\ 
\hline  8 nm &  490-580THz & 535THz & 16.82 \% \\ 
\hline  9 nm &  590-650THz & 620THz & 9.68 \%  \\ 
\hline  10 nm & 550-630THz & 590THz & 13.56 \% \\ 
\hline  11 nm & 590-640THz & 615THz & 8.13 \%  \\ 
\hline  12 nm & 560-660THz & 605THz & 16.53 \% \\ 
\hline  13 nm & 530-600THz & 565THz & 12.39 \% \\ 
\hline \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\textbf{hfjahdfjhadh}}\\
\hline  8 nm & 450-540THz & 595THz & 15.13 \%\\ 
\hline  10 nm &  530-620THz & 575THz & 15.65 \%\\ 
\hline  13 nm & 540-630THz & 585THz & 15.38 \%\\ 
\hline  15 nm &  540-610THz & 575THz & 12.17 \%\\ 
\hline  
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Now I want to get the file similar to the attached sample for two column IEEE Transaction LaTeX. Please help me out

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,siunitx,xcolor,colortbl}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\arrayrulecolor{blue!50}
\centering
\caption{jkhafj ahjfha hfjah fjahf jhasjf ha}
\label{Table1}
\begin{tabular}{ C{0.2\linewidth}  C{0.2\linewidth}  C{0.2\linewidth}  C{0.2\linewidth} }
 \toprule[0.5pt]
 \toprule[2pt]
\multicolumn{4}{c}{jkahfjadhfjhajfhahfa}\\
 \toprule[0.5pt]
 \toprule[2pt]
fhjahfa, `$r$' (\si{\nano\meter}) & ajlhfjkahfha (\si{\tera\hertz}) & ajhgjadhjgha (\si{\tera\hertz}) &     adhfjkdahfg (\%) \\\midrule
  8  &  490-580 & 535 & 16.82  \\
  9  &  590-650 & 620 & 9.68   \\
  10  & 550-630 & 590 & 13.56  \\
  11  & 590-640 & 615 & 8.13   \\
  12  & 560-660 & 605 & 16.53  \\
  13  & 530-600 & 565 & 12.39  \\
 \toprule[0.5pt]
 \toprule[2pt]
 \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{hfjahdfjhadh}}\\
 \toprule[0.5pt]
 \toprule[2pt]
  8  & 450-540 & 595 & 15.13 \\
  10  &  530-620 & 575 & 15.65 \\
  13  & 540-630 & 585 & 15.38 \\
  15  &  540-610 & 575 & 12.17 \\
 \toprule[0.5pt]
 \toprule[2pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But, it is better not to use vertical lines and double lines.